# Rename official postgres image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using an official Postgres12 image that I'm pulling inside the docker-compose.yml. Everything is working fine.

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - ...
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=...
```

Now, when I run docker-compose up, I get this image

[image]

My question is: is there a way in which I can rename the image **inside docker-compose.yml**? I know there is a command but I require it to be everything inside the file if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Knowing the reason behind this request might help people offer alternatives to this uncommon practice of masking an image name behind another.

Comment: @DannyB I require to everything contained in one file if possible, as I will be distributing the file with a team

Comment: But why do you need to rename the image?

Answer (score 1):

In a Compose file, there's no direct way to run `docker tag` or any other command that modifies some existing resource.

If you're trying to optionally point Compose at a local mirror of Docker Hub, you can take advantage of knowing the default repository is `docker.io` and use an optional environment variable:

```sh
image: ${REGISTRY:-docker.io}/postgres:latest
```

```sh
REGISTRY=docker-mirror.example.com docker-compose up
```

Another possible approach is to build a trivial image that doesn't actually extend the base `postgres` image at all:

```sh
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.postgres
image: local-images.example.com/my-project/postgres
```

```sh
# Dockerfile.postgres
FROM postgres:latest
# End of file
```

There's not really any benefit to doing this beyond the cosmetic appearances in the `docker images` output.  Having it be clear that you're using a standard Docker Hub image could be slightly preferable; its behavior is better understood than something you built locally and if you have multiple projects running at once they can more obviously share the same single image.